# Array entry as references function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

Probably simple question, but I am always a little bit confused with references and arrays as arguments. Is the following valid in C++? That is, does `array[0]` have the value `10` after call of `function1`, if the snippet comiples at all?

```
void function1(int &data)
{
  data = 10;
}

void function2(void)
{
  int array[2];

  function1(array[0]);
}
```

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: What exactly prevented you from testing this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will, and that's perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the following valid in C++?

Yes.

> > That is, does array[0] have the value 10 after call of function1, if the snippet comiples at all?

Yes.

Try compiling, run and experiment. Then ask the next - and slightly *better* -  question.

Comment: I actually think that telling people to compile and experiment is wrong. It's the nature of UB to run differently on every implementation or under different phases of the moon, and it's a bad idea to think that what worked when I tested it today would still work tomorrow, if I don't know that it's well-defined behaviour. Does it compile? Sure, you can test that. Is it valid? Most definitely not.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why telling people to compile and experiment is wrong? When did I say that if the program compiles and runs fine, then it's not UB? Also note that I said it **in addition to** TWO YES.

Comment: @DeadMG: Also, you said *Does it compile? Sure, you can test that. Is it valid? **Most definitely not**.* MOST Definitely not? Do you know what it implies?

Comment: @Nawaz: It means that you can most definitely not test something to see if it is valid, because it might appear to be valid but actually not be.